# Running into performance issues when working with a multi-chapter book

Tags: input, import

I am typesetting a 600+ page document on 6.125"x9" paper and running into two performance issues: TexStudio is becoming increasingly slow with its code-completion; and compilation is taking a very long time. There is very little markup, only chapters with drop caps, sections, and TOC - it is the sheer volume of the text (200+K words), which slows things down.

I have tried using both `\input` and `\import` equally unsuccessfully even after reading through at least a dozen answers on this resource. Every time the document either did not build, or built with only the content from the main file, but nothing from the included files.

Can anyone suggest a method, analogous to C `make`, for externalizing chapters of a document into external files and compiling only the changed files?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Compiling only the changed files will not work with LaTeX (except if you only want to get the output of the chapter that changed and even then I would not know of any tool that automates it). But could you be more specific why `\input` and `\include` don't work for you (after all `\input` is for TeX just the same as pasting the content of the other file in the main file and compiling that one)?

Comment: Did you use the `\includeonly` macro as well as `\include`?